# Multiple number of file attachments - DB Size issue

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

We have a XPages application where users attaches multiple file attachments. 
Within 2 month time, DB size has grown to 25GB, and we are now facing slowness in the system. 
Also, once the DB size hits certain size, domino will not allow to store any data in it and restrict the read access.

What is the best options to store the file attachments in some physical location directly instead of storing them in NSF file.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use DAOS to solve this.

**What does it do**

Its a server side task which separates the attachment and the document and stores the attachments on the file system (preferably on a separate volume) and the document in the nsf. This is a very low-level server task, and does not affect the standard lotuscript / xpages sdk.

Besides stripping it does de-deuplication, so if you have the same attachment in multiple documents or databases, only one copy of it is stored. This saves significant amount of space, especially for mailfiles.

**Gotchas**

You should be mindful about is the file size cut-off. If you strip all attachments it would result in large number of files on file system, which also degrades performance. So generally the best practice is to leave the small attachments <100k within the db. You can use the estimator tool http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27014980 to arrive at that number.

The tool that you use to backup should be capable of handling DAOS, and also backup the attachments.

Check here for detailed steps to activate this: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/DAOS_Deployment_Guide

Comment: ... and backup-wise you just have to include any new files from your DAOS directory. They are never changed.... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use DAOS. It's the official in-built tool for managing attachments and designed for exactly this scenario.